# How to generate a random tensor in custom Tensorflow Op Kernel

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen

I'm writing a custom tensorflow Op for the GPU and as part of the output of the forward computation I need a random tensor of shape (N,H,W).

I tried writing a function similar to the way I found a [zeros function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5b900cfe4b3b848f577315a0dde09a729f770e95/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/kernels/lstm_ops.h#L31) implemented:

```cpp
template <typename Device, typename T>
struct TensorRandom {
  void operator()(const Device& d, typename TTypes<T>::Flat t) {
  t.device(d) = t.random(); // this is my only change to the TensorZeros function
}
};
```

In the implementation/kernel of my op I have some code like

```cpp
TensorShape my_shape({N, H, W});
Tensor* random_mat;
OP_REQUIRES_OK(ctx, ctx->allocate_output("random_mat", my_shape, &random_mat));
const Device& device = ctx->eigen_device<Device>(); // this will be a gpu
functor::TensorRandom<Device, T>()(device, random_mat.flat<T>());

VLOG(1) << "Random Mat " << random_mat.shape().DebugString()
        << random_mat.SummarizeValue(N * H * W);
```

When I compile and run this I get this bizarre pattern below. If you flatten the tensor every element where `i%4==0` or `i%4==1` is repeated with a period of 4. The other numbers appear to be random enough.

```
Random Mat: (2,4,2) [[[0.93335256, 0.53328224],
        [0.18036943, 0.12565934],
        [0.93335256, 0.53328224],
        [0.042617  , 0.61869474]],

       [[0.93335256, 0.53328224],
        [0.70387461, 0.88239244],
        [0.93335256, 0.53328224],
        [0.76217792, 0.65087953]]]
```

I'm using single precision floating point. I've observed this on both NVIDIA V100 and Quadro M2200. Any tensor shape I try, I consistently get this pattern. I can't think of any hypotheses that would explain why this is happening.

Can anyone suggest a theory and perhaps a fix? Alternatively, I'd settle for an other method of getting `Tensor* random_mat` initialized with some random numbers that works. I'm not that familiar with the TensorFlow code base so this is the only thing I could think of doing

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How to use random number in user defined tensorflow op?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52600729/1782792). Random number generation in TensorFlow is rather complicated, I'm not sure whether you can use alternative methods to generate random numbers within an op... About what you are trying, I don't know if it could be that the function is not thread-safe and it is being called from multiple threads by TensorFlow...

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks for the link, I had missed that one. I still don't quite get how to get from your answer in that post to using it on the GPU. Do I need to copy everything in random_op_gpu.cu.cc? I would honestly settle for setting a tensorflow::Tensor on the GPU with an eigen::Tensor from the CPU since I don't have trouble generating random numbers on the CPU. Is there a constructor or setter method that would allow me to do this?

Comment: I think you can just use [`FillPhiloxRandom`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0/tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op.h) with the distribution that you want from [`random_distributions.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0/tensorflow/core/lib/random/random_distributions.h), like `FillPhiloxRandom<Device, random::UniformDistribution<random::PhiloxRandom, Type>>` (`Device` and `Type` are from your kernel template). See how it is used [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0/tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op.cc#L73-L84).

Comment: About copying memory from an Eigen tensor into the GPU, I'm not sure, but for that matter, would you be able to just eliminate the random number generation part from the op and have the random value as an input? So you could just get it from one of the existing random operations.

Comment: @jdehesa I'll give the FillPhiloxRandom thing a try and report back. Still not fully clear on how to do this but maybe it'll make more sense once I start doing it reading through the code more closely. Re passing the random tensor as an argument, in theory I suppose there's no reason that's not possible. However from an API perspective, I don't want the user to be responsible for having to create this as it does feel like an implementation detail. Something intrinsic to the op that the user shouldn't have to concern themselves with

Comment: At the bottom of [this](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html) page, (warning section) you can see that using random functions is not thread safe and it's because of the seed that each thread is using. In order to make your op thread-safe, one way is to feed a different (as far as you can) seed to your random function for *every* thread. I'm going to look for a more concrete solution and let you know if I find anything.

Comment: @Hamed I hadn't seen that page, thanks! I still don't quite get why the numbers have this pattern since if the seed is being repeated, I would think that all the numbers should be showing this non-random pattern. But I agree that warning indicates it's almost certainly the issue. 
My concern with doing one seed per thread is that I was reading that RNGs are designed for depth rather than breadth. As a result, taking a single number from each RNGs seeded with a different value might not be sufficiently random

Comment: Ideally I'd just create the random tensor on the CPU (single threaded) and set the `tensorflow::Tensor` data to be a copy of that but on the GPU. Alas, have not found a way of doing that yet

Comment: @jdehesa thanks again for your help! I've read through your other post and the source code and I'm convinced this is the correct way to get randoms. However, I've placed my op in contrib and when building it complains " undeclared inclusion(s) in rule <name of .so file being built>" and "_this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by_ <my_file.cc>:
  _'tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op.h'_". I tried adding "//tensorflow/core/kernels:random_ops" to srcs in BUILD but it doesn't like the dependence on framework

Comment: @Casey Yes, it seems that including that [`random_ops`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD#L4764-L4789) in the `deps` should be the solution, maybe that's a private target? See if adding one of the public targets [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0/tensorflow/core/BUILD#L5-L45) help (`:all_kernels` I think?).

Comment: @jdehesa Based on the build error, the issue seems to be that the random_ops target depends on [//tensorflow/core:framework](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/044ee2acf4c0705028479d0c21794933c2af92e3/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD#L4952). The definition of [tf_custom_op_library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/044ee2acf4c0705028479d0c21794933c2af92e3/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl#L1814) hardcodes the fact that you can't have any dependencies on framework or lib. Plenty of contrib files #include stuff from framework so I'm definitely misunderstanding something

Comment: For future users trying to do this, I wasn't ever able to get `FillPhiloxRandom` to work in contrib as the build rules don't seem to permit it. I ended up going with Hamed's solution and taking a random tensor as input which can be generate from `array_ops.random_uniform`. I don't surface this argument to the user in the python implementation of the op, though. I just have the user specify a noise level, generate the random tensor using `random_uniform`  behind the scenes and pass that to my Op